# Expanding the height of a div (including img) as text wraps

Tags: html, css

I am writing my own 'card' component where the title of the card should overlay over the image. The image should have a minimum height (in this case 100px) and then if the text overflows the image it should get larger. I've tried multiple StackOverflow threads but I can't seem to get the img to expand in size to the parent container (as the text wraps).

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.card-header {
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
.card-header img {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
.card-header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.card-header-text-title {
      font-size: 30px;
}
.card-header-text-author {
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png" alt="..."></img>
  <div class="card-header-text">
    <h3 class="card-header-text-title">A very exciting title title title title title</h3>
    <h4 class="card-header-text-author">John Smith</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png" alt="..."></img>
  <div class="card-header-text">
    <h3 class="card-header-text-title">A very exciting title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h3>
    <h4 class="card-header-text-author">John Smith</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as I mentioned I am trying to get the image to expand its parent div as the text wraps. Many thanks.

Comment: What happens if you make the image absolute position and the text div normal? If  the image overlaps just give it a negative z-index and it should fix it.

Comment: @Josie it still does the same thing when I do what you said

Comment: I would remove the images from the html and add the img to the background in .card-header-text   the attribute is background-image:url('your image path here');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

Set the position of the image to Absolute and z-index to -1 so it goes under the text.
Then you set the min-height of the card-header to 100px. And the rest should be fine!
Oh and remember that some elements, like images, don't need closing tags, I noticed you had put a , which is not needed.

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.card-header {
  position: relative;
  color: green;
  min-height:100px;
  width:100%;
}
.card-header img {
  display: block;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
.card-header-text {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.card-header-text-title {
      font-size: 30px;
}
.card-header-text-author {
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png" alt="..."/>
  <div class="card-header-text">
    <h3 class="card-header-text-title">A very exciting title title title title title</h3>
    <h4 class="card-header-text-author">John Smith</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>

<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png" alt="..."/>
  <div class="card-header-text">
    <h3 class="card-header-text-title">A very exciting title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title</h3>
    <h4 class="card-header-text-author">John Smith</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSs-Grid can do that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.card-header {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}

.card-header img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.card-header-text {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.card-header-text-title {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.card-header-text-author {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png" alt="..." />
  <div class="card-header-text">
    <h3 class="card-header-text-title">A very exciting title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title title
      title title</h3>
    <h4 class="card-header-text-author">John Smith</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-header">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png" alt="..." />
  <div class="card-header-text">
    <h3 class="card-header-text-title">A very exciting title</h3>
    <h4 class="card-header-text-author">John Smith</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yours works great thank you very much, but another answer involves changing less so will receive the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the image a background item. Here is what I suggest: 
in the css

```
.card-header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image:url('https://miro.medium.com/max/3000/1*vFubKHMcht1mSLSaHY6xLg.png');
}
```

and remove the image from the html.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few points you should take note:

1 - your `.card-header-text` should not be positioned with `absolute`, since you want its content to set the size of the parent element. Try using static or relative;

2 - `.card-header`'s height is set to 100px. According to your needs, 100px is actually its `min-height`. So set `min-height` to 100px and leave `height` as auto;

3 - lastly, your `img` should be absolute, since you don't want its height to sum to the parents' overall height.

Hope it helps!